# To prove $(a^2+b^2+c^2)(ab+bc+ca)^2 \ge (a^2+2bc)(b^2+2ca)(c^2+2ab)$.

Tags: inequality, summation, symmetric-polynomials

I think that there is not a simple proof of this inequality. (for all real numbers)

**My Attempt $1$:**
Equality occurs for $a=b=c$.

It is quit sure that the inequality is homogeneous.

So normalize with $ab+bc+ca = 1$.
$$
(a^2+b^2+c^2)(ab+bc+ca)^2
\ge
(a^2+2bc)(b^2+2ca)(c^2+2ab)
$$
$$
a^2+b^2+c^2
\ge
(a^2+2bc)(b^2+2ca)(c^2+2ab)
$$

We're done if
$$
1 \ge 2\sum_{cyc}{a^3b^3}+4\sum_{cyc}{a^4bc}+9a^2b^2c^2
$$
By the hypothesis,
$$
(ab+bc+ca)^3 $$$$= a^3 b^3 + 3 a^3 b^2 c + 3 a^3 b c^2 + a^3 c^3 + 3 a^2 b^3 c$$$$ + 6 a^2 b^2 c^2 + 3 a^2 b c^3 + 3 a b^3 c^2 + 3 a b^2 c^3 + b^3 c^3 $$$$= 1= \sum_{cyc}{a^3b^3} + 3\sum_{cyc}{a^3b^2c} + 3\sum_{cyc}{a^3bc^2}+6a^2b^2c^2
$$

$$
3\sum_{cyc}{a^3b^2c} + 3\sum_{cyc}{a^3bc^2}\ge \sum_{cyc}{a^3b^3}+4\sum_{cyc}{a^4bc}+3a^2b^2c^2
$$
As @Michael Rozenberg's feedback in one of my recent previous posts, I have carefully preserved the Equality case for 5 steps. Hope this helps!

I think that this inequality is sharp, as I have already used a blunt inequality. So I think SOS could work.

But this attempt is surely incorrect. Try $a=b=1$ and $c=0$.

**My Attempt $2$:**
Expand everything.
$$
(a^2+b^2+c^2)(ab+bc+ca)^2
\ge
(a^2+2bc)(b^2+2ca)(c^2+2ab)
$$
Here,
$$
(ab+bc+ca)^2 
= a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2 + 2abc(a+b+c) 
$$
$$
= \sum_{cyc}{a^2b^2}+2abc\sum_{cyc}{a}
$$
Multiplying this thing to $\sum_{cyc}{a^2}$ to get:

$$
= \sum_{cyc}{a^4b^2}+\sum_{cyc}{a^2b^4}+3a^2b^2c^2
$$
$$
+ 2abc (\sum_{cyc}{a^3}+\sum_{cyc}{a^2b}+\sum_{cyc}{ab^2})
$$
As before,
$$
(a^2+2bc)(b^2+2ca)(c^2+2ab)
$$
$$
= 2\sum_{cyc}{a^3b^3}+4abc\sum_{cyc}{a^3}+9a^2b^2c^2
$$
We just need to prove that:
$$
\sum_{cyc}{a^4b^2}+\sum_{cyc}{a^2b^4}+ 2abc (\sum_{cyc}{a^2b}+\sum_{cyc}{ab^2})
$$
$$
\ge 2\sum_{cyc}{a^3b^3}+2abc\sum_{cyc}{a^3}+6a^2b^2c^2
$$

From here, it's very easy to get a wrong inequality again:
As $(4,2)\succ(3,3)$.
$$
\sum_{cyc}{a^4b^2}+\sum_{cyc}{a^2b^4} \ge 2\sum_{cyc}{a^3b^3}
$$
It rests to prove that:
$$
\sum_{cyc}{a^2b}+\sum_{cyc}{ab^2}
\ge \sum_{cyc}{a^3} + 3abc
$$
Supplied
$$
\sum_{cyc}{ab^2} \ge 3abc
$$
The inequality is obviously wrong:
$$
\sum_{cyc}{a^2b} \ge \sum_{cyc}{a^3}
$$

I already have Vask's solution, so I don't need that proof.
I just ask if someone has another good solution, Thanks!

Comment: I may not know well, but does the fact that the sum of every terms in the left equals to the sum of the every terms in the right?

Comment: @JoshuaWoo You are right, that makes space to apply AM-GM.  And the fact that the inequality is homogeneous implies normalization. But simple AM-GM is difficult in my opinion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
\begin{eqnarray*}
(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a-a^2c-b^2a-c^2b)^2 \geq 0
\end{eqnarray*}
and this can be rearranged to give the required inequality.

Edit:

I first calculated that the inequality is equivalent to
\begin{eqnarray*}
& & (a^2+b^2+c^2)(ab+bc+ca)^2 -(a^2+2bc)(b^2+2ca)(c^2+2ab)  \\
&=& \sum_{cyc} a^4b^2 -2 \sum_{cyc} a^3 b^3 +2 \sum _{sym}a^3b^2c -6 a^2 b^2 c^2 \geq 0.
\end{eqnarray*}
The first two terms suggest the form above ... and luckily they also give the next two terms as well! ... $ \ddot \smile $

Comment: I reached to the expanded form $\sum_{cyc}{a^4b^2+a^2b^4-2a^3b^3 + 2a^3b^2c + 2a^3c^2b -2a^4bc - 2a^2b^2c^2}$. Could you mention in your answer how did you proceed from here?

Answer (score 4):

The first, it's easy to check
$$(x+a)(x+b)(x+c) = x^3+(a+b+c)x^2+(ab+bc+ca)x+abc.$$
So, setting $X=ab+bc+ca,$ we have
$$\prod (a^2+2bc) = \prod \left[X +(a-b)(a-c)\right]$$
$$=X^3+(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)X^2-(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2$$
$$=X^2\left[(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)+X\right]-(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2$$
$$=(ab+bc+ca)^2(a^2+b^2+c^2)-(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2$$
$$ \leqslant (ab+bc+ca)^2(a^2+b^2+c^2).$$

Comment: Very nice solution! +1

Comment: @nguyenhuyen_ag That is Vasc's solution. See the statement at the end of my post.

Comment: I don't know this is Vasile proof. If it's not my proof I will add info look like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3735618/if-x-y-z-in-mathbb-r-and-x3y3-z3-then-prove-that-x2y2-z26z/3736250#3736250) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3684753/410198).

Answer (score 2):

It's better to learn the following identities:
$$(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2,$$
$$(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2,$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$\left(\sum_{sym}a^2b\right)^2=\sum_{sym}(a^4b^2+a^3b^3+a^4bc+2a^3b^2c+a^2b^2c^2)$$ and
$$\prod_{cyc}(a-b)^2=\sum_{sym}(a^4b^2-a^3b^3-a^4bc+2a^3b^2c-a^2b^2c^2).$$
Now, we can solve your problem during one minute in one line by hand:
$$\sum_{cyc}a^2\left(\sum_{cyc}ab\right)^2-\prod_{cyc}(a^2+2bc)=$$
$$\sum_{cyc}a^2\sum_{cyc}(a^2b^2+2a^2bc)-\sum_{cyc}(2a^3b^3+4a^4bc+3a^2b^2c^2)=$$
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^4b^2+a^4c^2+a^2b^2c^2+2a^4bc+2a^3b^2c+2a^3c^2b)-\sum_{cyc}(2a^3b^3+4a^4bc+3a^2b^2c^2)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}(a^4b^2+a^4c^2-2a^3b^3-2a^4bc+2a^3b^2c+2a^3c^2b-2a^2b^2c^2)=\prod_{cyc}(a-b)^2\geq0.$$
The identity
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^4b^2+a^4c^2-2a^3b^3-2a^4bc+2a^3b^2c+2a^3c^2b-2a^2b^2c^2)=\prod_{cyc}(a-b)^2\geq0$$ we can get by the following way.

Let $a=b$.

Thus, we obtain:
$$2a^6+2a^4c^2+2c^4a^2-2a^6-4a^3c^3-4a^5c-2c^4a^2+4a^5c+4a^3c^3+4a^4c^2-6a^4c^2=0\cdot(a-c)^4$$ or
$$0=0,$$ which since our statement is symmetric and $a-b$ is not symmetric, we got a factor $(a-b)^2.$

Now, since our statement is symmetric, we have also factors $(a-c)^2$ and $(b-c)^2$ and since the left expression is sixth degree, we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^4b^2+a^4c^2-2a^3b^3-2a^4bc+2a^3b^2c+2a^3c^2b-2a^2b^2c^2)=C\prod_{cyc}(a-b)^2,$$ for some real number $C$.

Now, let $c=0$ and $b=1$.

We obtain for any real $a$:
$$a^4+a^2-2a^3=C(a-1)^2a^2,$$ which gives $C=1$.

Comment: I know the first $2$ identities as you mentioned. And I think you deployed them in the last step. Could you explain the identification a little more. I mean, the identities given are surely important, but how did you identify the combination in the step at the end? Isn't it so much chaotic?

Comment: @Book Of Flames I got this identity don't remember a number of years ago by full expanding $\prod\limits_{cyc}(a-b)^2=\prod\limits_{cyc}(a^2-2ab+b^2)=...=\sum\limits_{sym}(a^4b^2-a^4bc-a^3b^3+2a^3b^2c-a^2b^2c^2)$ and learned it. After it was written very easy to prove it: For $a=b$ or $b=c$ or $c=a$ we have a trivial identity: $0=0$. Now check a greatest coefficient, id est, the coefficient before $a^4b^2$.

Comment: Are these factorizations necessary evils? Well, Vasile Cirtoaje's book requires you to find new identities. Speaking of symmetric polynomials inequalities, I don't think $P1.17$ deserves that position.

Comment: @Book Of Flames See please my previous comment. I explained, how we can prove that the last identity is true (see again my words about highest coefficient). This reasoning you really can write in the competition. By the way, for me you don't need to make it. But if you want...

Comment: Yes please, it would be more clear.

Comment: @Book Of Flames See please my first comment. I explained it there. I am ready to explain again. Ask your questions.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how checking the greatest coefficient help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112560/discussion-between-book-of-flames-and-michael-rozenberg).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Both sides are symmetric polynomials. Express them in terms of elementary symmetric functions.

Comment: Do you mean the $pqr$ method? Please add more details.

Comment: You should get a nicer inequality because $p_1, p_2, p_3$ are essentially (not completely because of Vieta) arbitrary numbers.

Comment: In this case the RHS involves a symmetric product, this means that a great amount of effort is needed to proceed as you hinted (even though the expansion part is already done in the question).

Comment: Converting a symmetric polynomial is a routine procedure. In this case it is easy.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A = a^2 + b^2 + c^2$, $x = a- b$, $y = b - c$ and $z = c-a$. We have
\begin{align}
\mathrm{RHS} &= (A - y^2)(A - z^2)(A - x^2)\\
&= A^3 - A^2(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) + A(x^2y^2 + y^2z^2 + z^2x^2) - x^2y^2z^2\\
&= A^3 + 2A^2(xy+yz+zx) + A(xy+yz+zx)^2 - x^2y^2z^2\\
&= A(A + xy + yz + zx)^2 - x^2y^2z^2\\
&= (a^2 + b^2 + c^2)(ab+bc+ca)^2 - (a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2
\end{align}
where we have used
$$x+y+z = 0,$$
$$x^2+y^2+z^2 = (x+y+z)^2 - 2(xy+yz+zx) = -2(xy+yz+zx),$$
$$x^2y^2 + y^2z^2 + z^2 x^2 = (xy + yz + zx)^2 - 2xyz(x+y+z) = (xy + yz + zx)^2.$$

We are done.